# Use UIImagePicker to set the image in a UIImageView

Tags: swift, swift5

This is how my code currently looks like. What I expect to happen is the profileImage (UIImageView) to display the selected image as currently it is not happening.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var profileImage: UIImageView!

let picker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
}


    @IBAction func photoUploadPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.delegate = self;
            myPickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
            selectedImage = image
            profileImage.image = image
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Currently the Image Picker comes up, but once selected it does not change the UIImageView's image.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: remove this `let picker = UIImagePickerController()` also delete those 2 lines from `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Can you please specify issue?

Comment: what is `selectedImage` in your code ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as expected only error in your code is that you have } missing in `photoUploadPressed(_ sender: Any)` and you have not declared selectedImage & using it inside `imagePickerController`

**Working code**

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    }

    @IBAction func potoUploadPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
                   let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                   myPickerController.delegate = self;
                   myPickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                   self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }// It is missing in your code

    }


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
           if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
               selectedImage = image // You have not declared selectedImage
               profileImage.image = image
           }
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }

}
```